# Linked Lists - switch elements

Tags: c, linked-list

Im studing for an exam, and im a bit confused with my teacher class pdf's.

In switching elements (in this case X and Y ) on a linked list he has two different images that explain that, but there's only one way.

The problem is with the order of the connections, see the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnzL7.png

This is when you switch two elements (in this case X and Y) and you have to put the order of the connections, but i dont know what image is right :(

i already have tried to email him but he rarely reply to the students, and its common to see errors on his class pdf's

I need to know what image is the right one ,

Comment: Did you tried? where is your code?

Comment: Think carefully about each, and after each *individual* step in order presented, ask yourself if **every** node is still reachable.

Comment: Its not code, its an teorical exam, where he put the image without the order of the connections. we only see the broken ones, and we have to put the new connections with the trade of the X and Y.

The connections with numbers, dont appear in the exam, we have to put them. I dont know wich image have the right order of connections

Comment: They are both correct. The order of the operations does not matter as long as you can access the elements.

Comment: So long as `py` is provided they are both going to work. it should be food for thought how the second will *not* work without a `py`, yet the first works correctly without it.

Comment: hmm 'swap' elements would be closer, I was ready to see `switch (node->data){ case 0: ...}` ... a better exercise to study this would be to write a bubble or shell sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha those are confusing diagrams, at first. Such a simple concept, converted into such a complicated formula! What else is confusing? "Im studing... pdf's." Sigh. "...two different images that explain that, but there's only one way." One way what? Do you mean, one correct method? Not so! See the diagrams. They're both correct, you know. Observe the end result is the same. The difference is in the point of attack.

Might be easier to envision it this way: Rather than thinking of swapping X and Y in place, think of the procedure as pulling X completely out of the list, and reinserting it... where? Equivalently, try pulling Y completely out, and reinserting it where you want it. Same effect. Different approach. In fact, that's the difference between the two diagrams.

Now *I* have homework for *you*. Which is which? Which diagram pulls X first? Which pulls Y? Can you think of a third diagram? I can think of three more slight variations without even trying. (Edit: two main approaches, but variations in the reinsertion.) In the end, it's not about memorising a formula. It's *never* about memorising a formula. Well, almost never. It's about visualising the effect you're after, and filling in the blanks.